# Intermittent connection failures when using Google Translation API using the C# API

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-translation-api

I am getting intermittent errors when using the Google translation C# APIs. Weirdly enough I never ever get the error on my local PC, it's only when I run it on our Test and Prod servers do I get the error.

The code is straightforward.

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(@"
{
  // .....text from my google credentials json file
}");

var client = TranslationClient.Create(credential);
var response = client?.TranslateText("Hello World.", "fr");
```

The error I get is

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, String tokenServerUrl, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IClock clock)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ExecuteUnparsedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.TranslationClientImpl.TranslateText(IEnumerable`1 textItems, String targetLanguage, String sourceLanguage, Nullable`1 model)
   at Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.TranslationClient.TranslateText(String text, String targetLanguage, String sourceLanguage, Nullable`1 model)
   at QuickStart.Main(String[] args)
```

I suspect the error is in the authentication code. Curiously it seems to work on the servers in spurts, so connects and translates fine for a period of time, and then stops to do so, throwing the aforementioned error.

Do I need a separate key for every server? 
As I said before works flawlessly on my PC - Every. Single. Time.

I am on the currently on a basic account, so not sure if there are any thresholds that I am breaching, but could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Intermittent as in sometimes it works in the higher environments? And sometimes it doesn't? Or intermittent as in it works only locally for debugging?

Comment: Intermittent as in sometimes works in higher environments and sometimes doesn't. It always works locally.